# LayoutInflater в Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Нужно несколько раз использовать один и тот же View.

Сейчас код выглядит так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.pet, null, false);
    // body         
    createView.onView(view);
}
```

Я понимаю что каждый раз заново доставать layout не ОКЕЙ. Если я получаю View вне цикла, получается ошибка. Так вот, как мне один раз достать layout, и использовать его несколько раз?

ListView не предлагайте плиз

Comment: Задача как раз для ListView похоже. Можете привести пример, что хочется получить в результате и как вы "получаете view вне цикла"?

Comment: Сделал меню, сверху для фоток используется ListView, снизу для пунктов меню LinearLayout, и туда добавляю пункты, таким способом как выше. https://pp.vk.me/c621823/v621823970/25634/HkvOXbkBP30.jpg

Comment: 1. Желательно в метод inflate передавать parent.
2. В любом случае необходимо создавать новое view.
3. Можете вынести LayoutInflater за пределы цикла.
4. Ошибку получаете из-за того что у view уже установлен parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Желательно в метод inflate передавать parent.
2. В любом случае необходимо создавать новое view.
3. Можете вынести LayoutInflater за пределы цикла.
4. Ошибку получаете из-за того что у view уже установлен parent.

Пример:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pet, null, false);
    //body
    createView.onView(view);
}
```

Comment: parent ведь можно удалять?

Comment: Да, [ViewGroup.detachViewFromParent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#detachViewFromParent(android.view.View))

Comment: @antop95, зачем это надо ?

Comment: например что бы каждый раз не тянуть файл разметки из памяти. Это навернека затратно очень

Comment: @antop95 , можешь подробнее описать свою задачу

Comment: есть список сообщений, в каждом сообщении может быть несколько фото, и мне нужно в каждом сообщении из отобразить

Comment: Если тебе известно максимально возможное количество фоток (к примеру 5), то сгенерируй View с максимальным количеством и не нужным ставь View.setVisibility(View.GONE).